# Watson Machine Translation in Node Red Flow

Tags: node-red

It seems there have been some changes in the usage of the Machine Translation service from within a Node Red flow. There was the capability to configure from within the node from which into which other language to translate. This has been changed. Can you help me in understanding where to set exactly this when having identified the language already before (msg.lang)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to set the translation language for the Machine Translation node.

You can either...

- Select the language from the dropdown menu in the node configuration dialog.

[image: node configuration]

- Pass the language translation type as the "lang" parameter on the "msg" object.

Supported language types for the Machine Translation node are automatically registered at runtime. You must have the Watson Machine Translation Service bound to your Node-RED instance running on Bluemix.